# While generating dropdownlist with ng-options, how to set the selected option?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

Here is the plnker [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ofEQfqgiV8JJplejrZd8?p=info)

In the `script.js`, I create a variable `info` to store the options. The selected option should be "Spanish" because,

```
 {
     "name": "Spanish", 
     "value": 3082, 
     "selected": true //It's true here.
 }
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `ng-model`. Based on your `info.value.lang` you can set the `selected : true` to the model value.

```
function MyCntrl($scope) {
    $scope.info = info;
    $scope.selectedItem = null;

    angular.forEach(info.value.lang, function(lang) {
      if (lang.selected === true){
        $scope.selectedItem = lang.value;
      }
    });
}

<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in info.value.lang" >
  </select>
</div>
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/RMr19uwuOH3EEjMd7cRL

Comment: @0n1yDream: Some typo in your plunker `"value;": 3082,` and `"value;": 6666,`. I added the `test` object in my plunker. Please check my plunker.

Comment: I meet another problem: when I select one option, for example "test", I want to change the selected value of "Spanish" to false and the selected value of "test" to true. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your original plunkr you used data in the HTML while your variable in the scope is called info. Using ng-repeat instead of ng-options I got it to work like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
  <select >
    <option ng-repeat="option in info.value.lang" selected="option.selected">{{ option.name }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/jp8g65LDtft1ZVvJe8nz

Which also gets the result you want if I interpreted your question right.

Edit: Oh by the way, selected should be selected='selected' and not by a boolean.

Comment: Its ok with `ng-repeat`.. But is there any way to do the same with `ng-options`??

Comment: Yeah I guess the answer Arulkumar posted is better and it uses ng-options.

Comment: This only works when the selected is the last option. If I modify the variable info as shown in [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/dKllfAVK0bhd92fXe1LG) , the selected option is wrong

Comment: I didn't edit the info variable in your JS. But as i mentioned in the edit selected works with =selected, not true or false.

Answer (score 0):

You have used different variable name in the js and in the html. The ngOptions needs to have a model. For setting Spanish as the default you have to do something like this.

```
<body>
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
  <select ng-model="someModel" ng-init="someModel=3082" ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in info.value.lang">
  </select>
</div>
</body>
```

Here someModel will have the selected value from the options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `ng-model` check this link it is working now..
[plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/EC6RT9TxfxmqIBDe74rO/preview)